# Изменения стиля меню "li a:active" при нажатии

Tags: jquery, style, javascript

Всем привет.
Возникла проблема: не знаю, как написать `onlick`-функцию:
при нажатии на меню либо кнопку к ней приписывается стиль `"style=background:#0099FF"`

```
<li><a href="javascript:showonlyone('statistics');" onclick="statistics(); this.style(background:#0099FF)">Statistics</a></li>
```

Попробовал так - не работает. Надеюсь, кто-то поможет.
На `javascrift:showonlyone` не обращяйте внимания.

Comment: Вопрос решен.

Comment: а почему с помощью CSS не решить? Суля по всему вам нужно поменять цвет в момент клика, CSS прекрасно решает эту задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так this.style.backgroundColor='#0099FF'

И проверьте выполнение кода после функции statistics(); возврат из нее есть?

Comment: Спасибо, так работает, но после нажатия не исчезает хД.   
Как пофиксить данную проблему?

Comment: Не понял, что не исчезает?)

Comment: эффект active после перехода в другое меню не пропадает с прошлого )

Answer (score 0):

Начните использовать jQuery и почитайте про ненавязчивый JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4e8ncrp/